# loading multiple arrays of char and int type in one while loop from a text file

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my first attempt at writing a program.  I am trying to take a text file similar to this:

```
1 EAME    B170 4
```

It continues the 4 values in columns for hundreds of iterations.

Then use a while loop to input each column into arrays.  The data is being input wrong because of my current while loop.  I can see from using the step by step debugger that the first column is gathered and placed into "monthDemand" array, but after that everything fails.  The EAME is placed into the char region array with other junk data and the "B170" is split.  Only the B is assigned to "dealerCode" and the "170" gets assigned to "unitsDemanded" which should be the 4th column of inputs. Here is my function attempting to load the arrays:

```
void loadDemandArrays (int monthDemand [], char region [], char dealerCode [], int     unitsDemanded [], int limitDemand, int maxRegion, int maxDealerCode) {
//open the Demand file and abort the program if file not found
ifstream infileDemand;
infileDemand.open ("Demand.txt");
if (!infileDemand) {
    cerr << "Cannot open Demand.txt\n";
    exit (1);
}

// Input all data into arrays from the Demand File
int i = 0;
int lineNumberDemand = 1;
while (i < limitDemand && infileDemand) {
    infileDemand >> monthDemand[i] >> ws;
    infileDemand.get (region, sizeof(region));
    infileDemand.get (dealerCode, sizeof(dealerCode));
    infileDemand >> unitsDemanded [i];
    i++;
    lineNumberDemand++;
}
```

I have been stuck reading resources and retrying edits that are not working.  Can someone tell me if what I am trying to do is possible the way I am doing it or suggest a good reference that would explain?

Comment: You probably want to read up on `struct`s right about now. At least from the looks of things, this is probably best handled with something like a vector of structs.

Comment: Half of the problem here is reading `region` and `dealerCode` using raw bytes, and the fact that `sizeof(region)` will return the size of a pointer, not the actually array.  You should use `std::string` and just read the values the same way you read everything else.  Whitespace will be handled automatically.  Even better, read a single line using `std::getline`, then parse the stuff out of a `std::istringstream`.  There's heaps of examples on SO dealing with that.

Comment: Thank you both for your help.  This has gotten me unstuck and moving on my program again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tiny sample program that should get you started. It reads the file line by line, splits the line by space delimeter and outputs to console the results. There are some restrictions. There should be exactly for groups of characters in each string of the file separated by spaces. The first and the last elements of each string must only contain integer numbers.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) 
{
    std::vector<std::string> elements;
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        elements.push_back(item);
    }
    return elements;
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("data.txt", std::ifstream::in);

    std::string lineRed;
    for (;;)
    {
        getline(file, lineRed);
        if (0 == lineRed.length())
        {
            break;
        }

        std::vector<std::string> elems = split(lineRed, ' ');
        if (elems.size() == 4)
        {
            int month = atoi(elems[0].c_str());
            std::string code = elems[1];
            std::string region = elems[2];
            int amount = atoi(elems[3].c_str());

            //Do something with extracted values here
            //Just print 'em to stdout for the test purpose:
            std::cout<< "Month:" << month << " Code:" << code << " Region: " << region << " Amount: " << amount;

        }
        lineRed.clear();

    }
}
```